# D3.js Force Directed Graph, how to update a single node on "click"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to update the position of a single node in a for directed graph following a click event?

```
http://jsfiddle.net/typeofgraphic/jx501n0r/2/
```

The nodes are set with different attributes when they first load. What I am trying to achieve is for a clicked node to reposition itself (without reloading the entire graph) based on a change in value ("active" in this case).

I have tried this a few different ways. It is important that the graph does not reload on the page, other nodes can move to accommodate the clicked node to move but reloading the page is not an option.

Here is the code:

```
var ds = {
    nodes: [
        { name: "1", active: false },
        { name: "2", active: false },
        { name: "3", active: true },
        { name: "4", active: false },
        { name: "5", active: false },
        { name: "6", active: true },
        { name: "7", active: false },
        { name: "8", active: true },
        { name: "9", active: false },
        { name: "10", active: false },
        { name: "11", active: true },
        { name: "12", active: false },
        { name: "13", active: false },
        { name: "14", active: false }
    ],
    edges: [
        { source: 0, target: 1 , value: 10},
        { source: 4, target: 1, value: 40 },
        { source: 5, target: 1, value: 40 },
        { source: 6, target: 1, value: 40 },
        { source: 7, target: 1, value: 10 },
        { source: 8, target: 1, value: 40 },
        { source: 9, target: 1, value: 40 },
        { source: 10, target: 1, value: 40 },
        { source: 11, target: 1, value: 40 },
        { source: 12, target: 1, value: 40 },
        { source: 13, target: 1, value: 40 }
    ]
};

var w = 300,
    h = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(ds.nodes)
        .links(ds.edges)
        .linkDistance(function(d){ return d.active == true ? [10] :[200] })
        .charge(function(d){ return d.active == true ? [-100] :[-50] })
        .size([w, h]);

force.on("tick", function() {

    edges.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    nodes.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
});

// Restart the layout.
force.start();

// DRAW EDGES
var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
        .data(ds.edges)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .style("stroke", "#ccc")
        .style("stroke-width", 1);

// DRAW NODES
var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(ds.nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("r", 10)
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
.style("fill", function(d) { 
    return d.name === "primary" ?  "#466BB0" : "dark-grey"; })
.style("stroke", "white")
.style("stroke-width", "1.5px")
.call(force.drag);

// CLICK EVENTS
nodes.on("click", function(d){
    d.active = true;
    console.log(d.active)

    d3.select(this).transition().style({
        fill: "red" 
    });

    // Restart the layout.
    //force.start();

    edges.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    nodes.attr("transform", function(d) { console.log(d); return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });


})
```

Comment: Set the `fixed` attribute of the datum representing the node to `true` and its `x` and `y` attributes accordingly. You may need to restart the force layout to make the `tick` handler pick up the new position.

Comment: the fixed attribute does get set to true in the click event function. The x and y coordinates are determined by the functions within .charge and .linkDistance, you can see a force.start() call at the bottom which is commented out. It doesn't force anything to be redrawn which is what I expected. Maybe you could be more explicit, perhaps I misinterpreted your comment?

Comment: Ok, now I'm not sure what you mean anymore. Do you want to "step" the simulation on click or do you want to move the clicked node to a new, fixed position?

Comment: I don't mind the method, but I can't have the graph disappear completely and be redrawn. There is a link to the code on jsfiddle at the top, fixed position is ok but I am happy at this stage for the graph just to re-run (update) and adjust the nodes where the data has changed i.e. move its position based on a change in attribute value (active: true)

Comment: As I've said above, to move the node to a new, fixed position on click, you need to set the `fixed`, `x` and `y` attributes for it.